# Visa Electron regular expression not matching string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Why isn't my credit card regular expression not matching the Visa Electron number provided in the console.log I have added the prefix to the start which 4844 and it still will not match

```js
const cards = [
            {
                name: 'Visa Electron',
                length: '16',
                prefixes: '4026,4175,4405,4508,4844,4913,4917',
                regexp: /^(4026|4175|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)[0-9]{16}$/          
            }];
            
console.log(cards[0].regexp.test('4844640696905509'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression

```
(4026|4175|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)[0-9]{16}
```

matches a total of 20 characters: first, one of the 4-character sequences in the alternated group, and then 16 numbers.

Match 12 numbers afterwards, so you get 4 + 12 = 16.

```js
const cards = [
            {
                name: 'Visa Electron',
                length: '16',
                prefixes: '4026,4175,4405,4508,4844,4913,4917',
                regexp: /^(?=4026|4175|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)[0-9]{16}$/          
            }];
            
console.log(cards[0].regexp.test('4844640696905509'))
```

Another approach in this sort of situation is to lookahead instead of matching with the group.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand something new from regular expression since I asked this question, your answer is very much appreciated. cheers